# Arrange these functions in descending order: $\tan x^{\tan x}$, $\tan x^{\cot x}$, $\cot x^{\tan x}$, $\cot x^{\cot x}$, for $x\in(0,\pi/4)$

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

> Given $$t_1=\tan x^{\tan x}$$
> $$t_2=\tan x^{\cot x}$$
> $$t_3=\cot x^{\tan x}$$
> $$t_4=\cot x^{\cot x}$$
> for $x\in(0, \frac{\pi}{4})$. Arrange them in descending order.

I tried in this way:

in  $(0, \frac{\pi}{4})$ from the graphs of $\tan x$ and $\cot x$ $$\cot x \gt \tan x$$ and in  $(0, \frac{\pi}{4})$ both are positive  we have
$$\cot x^{\cot x} \gt \tan x^{\cot x}$$ that is

$$t_4 \gt t_2$$  and similarly

$$\cot x^{\tan x} \gt \tan x^{\tan x}$$ that is

$$t_3 \gt t_1$$

Now only comparison left is between $t_4$ and $t_1$.

if $f(x)=x^x$ it is decreasing in $(0, \frac{1}{e})$ and increasing from $(\frac{1}{e}, \frac{\pi}{4})$

so in $(0, \frac{1}{e})$ since $\cot x \gt \tan x$ we get
$$\cot x^{\cot x} \lt \tan x^{\tan x}$$ that is

$$t_4 \lt t_1$$

hence in $(0, \frac{1}{e})$ $$t_3 \gt t_1 \gt t_4 \gt t_2$$

and in  $(\frac{1}{e}, \frac{\pi}{4})$ since $x^x$ is increasing we get $$\cot x^{\cot x} \gt \tan x^{\tan x}$$ that is

$$t_4 \gt t_1$$

but i cannot arrange them in decreasing order in $(\frac{1}{e}, \frac{\pi}{4})$

Comment: You should study all the $\frac{t_i}{t_j}$ it would be easier

Comment: This reminds me of Exercise V.f #20 on p. 102 of Durell/Robson's [**Advanced Trigonometry**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0486432297). I'm pretty sure I've previously posted this exercise somewhere in MSE (or in [MESE](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/)), but I can't find it now.

Comment: Here's the Durell/Robinson exercise: "If $x$ is small, show that the following functions can be arranged in ascending order of magnitude by expanding in powers of $x,$ as far as $x^3$ only, and arrange them: (i) $\sin({\tan}^{-1}x);$ (ii) $\tan({\sin}^{-1}x);$ (iii) ${\tan}^{-1}({\tan}^{-1}x);$ (iv) $\tan(\tan x);$ (v) $\sin(\sin x);$ (vi) ${\sin}^{-1}({\sin}^{-1}x).$"

Answer (score 1):

Set $y = \tan x$. Then $y \in (0,1)$ and

- $t_1 = y^y$
- $t_2 = y^{1/y}$
- $t_3 = y^{-y}$
- $t_4 = y^{-1/y}$

We got rid of the noise. Since $\log$ in increasing, this is the same of comparing

- $\log t_1 = y \log y$
- $\log t_2 = \dfrac{1}{y} \log y$
- $\log t_3 = -y \log y$
- $\log t_4 = -\dfrac{1}{y} \log y$

It's obvious that $$-\frac{1}{y} < -y < y < \frac{1}{y}$$
Multiplying by $\log y <0$ we get $$-\frac{1}{y}\log y > -y\log y > y \log y > \frac{1}{y} \log y$$

which means $$t_4>t_3>t_1>t_2$$

Answer (score 0):

Let me try this way : 
 In $(0,$$\pi\over 4$$)$ , $\tan x <1 $ and $\cot x >1$ 
 I make a statement - *Anything less than one to the power of a positive number, is less than one!*

Another statement - *Anything greater than one to the power of a positive number, is greater than one*

So, I say, $\cot > \tan$

Well, From your statements, *since $x^x$ is decreasing,* doesn't mean $cot (x) ^ {cot(x)}$ should decrease right?.